# Return vector of row index values for a list of elements in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix that looks like this:
[image]

I need to be able to extract a list of the row indices for matches in the column of data.  For example, if I wanted to search for 't1', 't3', and 't5' I need the values returned to be 1, 9 and 2.

I envision something like:

```
searchstring<-"t1", "t2", "t3"
rowindexofmatches<-match(matrix, searchstring)
print(rowindexofmatches)
#output should be "10,1,9"
```

but being fairly inexperienced with R I have not been able to get this to work.

Comment: `which(matrix[,1] %in% searchstring)`

Comment: By the way, your `searchstring` is invalid. It needs `c()`.

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you both.